# Firewall rules for accessing Google-Cloud-Storage from the outside world

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, domain-name, google-cloud-storage

I'm deploying an application that relies on GCS at a customer's site.
The customer's firewall allows whitelisting domains for outgoing connections, so I've whitelisted the known GCS domains (storage.googleapis.com , googleapis.com  , crl.pki.goog)

However, since GCS uses CNAME redirects, sometimes a request to storage.googleapis.com gets redirected to another address,  for example "storage.l.googleusercontent.com"

How can I get a comprehensive list of all the domains to whitelist ?
what if additional domains are added in the future ? is there a way to whitelist them ?

Thanks,
Yair

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#proxy-server) you need to whitelist `accounts.google.com` and `*.googleapis.com`.

Using `dig` at `storage.googleapis.com`:

```
$ dig storage.googleapis.com
```

I get this:

```
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
storage.googleapis.com. 3448    IN      CNAME   storage.l.googleusercontent.com.
[...]
```

So you can see that `storage.l.googleusercontent.com` is an alias from `storage.googleapis.com`

For `accounts.google.com` there is no alias.

If in the future are added new domains, you will be able to whitelist them by the same way you whitelisted all these domains.